# Power series representation of MeijerG function, $G_{m,n}^{p,q}(x)$

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I've been experimenting with Mathematica and I keep getting the following (where $G_{m,n}^{p,q}(x)$ is the MeijerG function):

[image]

Is it possible to express those $f_{i}(x)$ as a power series in $x$? Please keep in mind this specific pattern $(2,...,2)|(1,1,...,1)$.

The following is and example returned by Mathematica

```
MeijerG[{{}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {}}, x]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use Series. Look it up in the documentation.

Comment: `FunctionExpand[]` should give you expressions involving `HypergeometricPFQ[]`, whose series is not too hard to construct, and a logarithmic part with powers of `Log[]`, which may be troublesome.

Comment: @J.M. I left a similar comment on the answer below, but I wanted to include you in the conversation as well. I am trying to wrap my head around something here. `MeijerG[...] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify` returns an expression for whom numerical values can be calculated orders of magnitude faster than for `MeijerG[...]` itself. Does it introduce a loss of generality? Or alternatively, *why is that not the way that* `MeijerG` *values are calculated internally*?!

Comment: @Marco, I've not fully spelunked the code for `MeijerG[]`, but I am certain that it is using a general numerical evaluation method (based on evaluating a contour integral), which, while general, is not terribly fast. In this specific case (which I would say is due to the simple integer parameters), it thankfully degenerates to the sum of a hypergeometric function and a logarithmic part, both of which are (comparatively) easier to compute. This is why attempting `FunctionExpand[]` on `MeijerG[]` is (sometimes) profitable.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

As suggested by J.M.

```
f[x_] = MeijerG[{{}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {}}, x] // 
  FunctionExpand // FullSimplify

(* 1/12 x (12 x HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, -x] - 
  (EulerGamma + Log[x]) (2 EulerGamma^2 + π^2 + 
      2 Log[x] (2 EulerGamma + Log[x])) - 4 Zeta[3]) *)

NMaximize[{f[x], x > 0}, x]

(* {0.20205, {x -> 0.067003}} *)

Limit[f[x], x -> 0]

(* 0 *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to wrap my head around something here. `MeijerG[...] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify` returns an expression for whom numerical values can be calculated *orders of magnitude faster* than `MeijerG` itself. What loss of generality does it introduce? Or alternatively, why is that not the way that `MeijerG` values are calculated internally?!

Comment: I do not know. Recommend that you post this as a question.

Comment: OK Thanks. I was wondering if I was missing something obvious here.